# DRY for rendering same header table for different content

Tags: python, template, django

I'm trying to make the following code DRY. The code outputs a table that shows violations. If there is any `violation.status = resolved` they go in separate table for resolved items. Since the header and columns of the table are the same, I believe I should be able to make this DRY using a `For loop`. However, I'm not sure that's possible in Django templates.

There's three relevant context variables:

1. violation_list which is a query set of all violations
2. not_resolved_violations which is (1) excluding status = resolved
3. resolved_violations which is (1) filtered on status = resolved

---

```
{% if violation_list %}

{% if not_resolved_violations %}
<h3>Open Violations</h3>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center">#</th>
        <th class="text-center">IDENTIFIER</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
{% for violation in not_resolved_violations %}


    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href='#'>{{ violation.identifier }}</a></td>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>

{% endif %}


{% if resolved_violations %}
<h3>Resolved Violations</h3>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center">#</th>
        <th class="text-center">IDENTIFIER</th>
                                    </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
{% for violation in resolved_violations %}


    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href='#'</a></td>

     </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>

{% endif %}


{% else %}
<p>This project doesn't have any violations associated it with it.</p>
{% endif %}

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try building a slightly more complex datastructure to be passed in.  If you built a list like:

```
violations = [ ("Resolved", resolved_violations), 
               ("Open", unresolved_violations) ]
```

Then you could write a template like:

```
{% for vtype, vlist in violations %}
    {% if vlist %}
<h3>{{ vtype }} Violations</h3>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center">#</th>
        <th class="text-center">IDENTIFIER</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
        {% for violation in vlist %}
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href='#'>{{ violation.identifier }}</a></td>
     </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew a list would fix my problem. Not sure why I kept on trying to do it in template instead of the view. I believe `{% vtype %}` should be replaced with `{{ vtype }}` in your example. Edit: Also to be able to show the no violations available message I added the following if statement: `{% if violations.0.1 or violations.1.1 %}